# DRF error create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'hnid'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

so I am building a pet blog project where my scenario is - my users will be able to post multiple images and audios if they want while doing so , am facing several problems -

1. while trying to post through POSTMAN . I am getting an error saying create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'hnid' ..
   [image]
2. while querying using UUID , it is throwing , a String naming "HNUsers object (e3ec1a43-ebc4-47b9-bf2f-55967af8ea71)" where I just wanted UUID(e3ec1a43-ebc4-47b9-bf2f-55967af8ea71) but came with extra HNUsers object [image]

Here is my  Profile model

```
class HNUsers(models.Model):
    USERTYPE = (
        (u'RU', u'REGULAR USER'),
        (u'HN', u'HN'),
    )

    GENDER = (
        (u'M', u'Male'),
        (u'F', u'Female'),
        (u'O', u'Other'),
    )

    ip_address = models.CharField("IP Address" , max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField("Full Name", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField("Username", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField("Email", blank=True, null=True)
    user_type = models.CharField("User Type", max_length=2, choices=USERTYPE, null=True, blank=True, default=USERTYPE[0][0])
    mobile_number = models.CharField("Mobile Number", max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField("Date of Birth", auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField("Gender", max_length=1, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True, )
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField("Registration Date", auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField("City", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField("Country", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_img = models.ImageField("Profile Image", blank=True, null=True)
    first_img = models.FileField("First Image", blank=True, null=True)
    first_img_url = models.CharField("First Image Url", blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    profile_img_url = models.CharField("Profile Image Url", blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    hnid = models.UUIDField("HNID", default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

**my imagepost model**

```
class ImagePost(models.Model):
    hnid = models.ForeignKey("profiles.HNUsers", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    file = models.FileField("Image", blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField("Timestamp", blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField("Description text", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Image Posts"
```

**serializer for image post**

```
class MultiMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField(max_length=100, allow_empty_file=False, use_url=True))

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        # print(validated_data)
        files = validated_data.pop('file')
        print(files)
        user = HNUsers.objects.get(pk=request.data['hnid'])

        print("hnid ", user)
        # print("hnid ", entry)
        for img in files:
            print(img)
            photo = ImagePost.objects.create(file=img, hnid=user,  **validated_data)
        return photo

    class Meta:
        model = ImagePost
        fields = ('hnid', 'file',)
```

Views.py file for the above is -

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, FormParser])
def posting_api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        print(data)

        serializer = MultiMediaSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("image object saved")
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Remove **`hnid=user`** from the create statement since the `validated_data` does have the `hnid` field already

```
 photo = ImagePost.objects.create(file=img,  **validated_data)
```

Comment: Thanks .. It works but comes up with " HNUsers object (e3ec1a43-ebc4-47b9-bf2f-55967af8ea71) " how can I get just UUID from it? sorry for the silly question